# How to send data use mpi4py across multiple nodes?

Tags: python, mpi, slurm, mpi4py

everyone:
I run my code on the hpc,but I can't transmit data between nodes. I write a simple code to test the communications between cores across nodes. First, I use one node 8 cores, my code is(`test.py`)

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys
import numpy as np

def print_hello(rank, size, name):
  msg = "Hello World! I am process {0} of {1} on {2}.\n"
  sys.stdout.write(msg.format(rank, size, name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
    rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
    name = MPI.Get_processor_name()
    if rank == 0:
        data = np.random.random((8,64,64,64))
        print(data.shape)
    else:
        data = None

    data = comm.scatter(data,root=0)
    print(data.shape)

    print_hello(rank, size, name)
```

and I run it use the `srun -N 1 -n 8 python3 test.py 2>&1 | tee out.txt`, it just like `mpirun -np 8 python3 test.py 1>&1 | tee out.txt`, it runs only 5 seconds
The `out.txt` file is :

```
(64, 64, 64)
Hello World! I am process 4 of 8 on cn3478.
(64, 64, 64)
Hello World! I am process 5 of 8 on cn3478.
(64, 64, 64)
Hello World! I am process 6 of 8 on cn3478.
(64, 64, 64)
Hello World! I am process 7 of 8 on cn3478.
(64, 64, 64)
Hello World! I am process 1 of 8 on cn3478.
(64, 64, 64)
Hello World! I am process 2 of 8 on cn3478.
(64, 64, 64)
Hello World! I am process 3 of 8 on cn3478.
(8, 64, 64, 64)
(64, 64, 64)
Hello World! I am process 0 of 8 on cn3478.
```

everything looks good!
However, When I use two nodes 48 cores, it went wrong! The file is that(`test48.py`):

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys
import numpy as np

def print_hello(rank, size, name):
  msg = "Hello World! I am process {0} of {1} on {2}.\n"
  sys.stdout.write(msg.format(rank, size, name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
    rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
    name = MPI.Get_processor_name()
    if rank == 0:
        data = np.random.random((48,64,64,64))
        print(data.shape)
    else:
        data = None

    data = comm.scatter(data,root=0)
    print(data.shape)

    print_hello(rank, size, name)
```

I run it through `yhrun -N 2 -n 48 python3 test48.py 2>&1 | tee out2.txt`
It runs a lot of time(more than 1 hour) and did't print anything. I guess that the data transmission went wrong because I comment out the two lines:

```
    data = comm.scatter(data,root=0)
    print(data.shape)
```

The code is completed quickly and the output is :

```
Hello World! I am process 25 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 28 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 30 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 31 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 32 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 40 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 41 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 44 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 24 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 26 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 27 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 29 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 33 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 34 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 35 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 36 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 37 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 38 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 42 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 43 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 45 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 46 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 47 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 39 of 48 on cn3598.
Hello World! I am process 1 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 3 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 4 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 9 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 12 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 15 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 16 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 17 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 20 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 2 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 5 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 6 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 7 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 8 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 10 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 11 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 13 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 14 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 18 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 19 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 21 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 22 of 48 on cn3597.
Hello World! I am process 23 of 48 on cn3597.
(48, 64, 64, 64)
Hello World! I am process 0 of 48 on cn3597.
```

What's wrong is the code? or the data transmission between nodes is not allowed? Any suggestion is welcomed!

Comment: Now I know it, the data is to large, if I transmit data which shape is (48,48,48), it works well across nodes. Is there a size limitation when transmit data? Could I change the limitation? or is there anyway to avoid it ?

Comment: Your data sizes are not really that large - even your large array is only 96MiB. However, to check for any limits or inter-node issues try running on 48 processes but with a much smaller dataset, e.g. 48x8x8x8.